# $(A\times A)\cup (B\times C)=(A\cup B)\times (A\cup C)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I need to Prove or disprove this:
$(A\times A)\cup (B\times C)=(A\cup B)\times (A\cup C)$
thanks

```
I'm editing my question: 
How do I continue?
    (A∪B)×(A∪C)=(A×A)∪(B×C)
⟸
(x,y)∈(A×A)∪(B×C)
(x,y)∈(A×A)∪(x,y)∈(B×C)
(x∈A∩y∈A)∪(x∈B∩y∈C)
(x∈A∪x∈B)∩(y∈A∪y∈C)
x∈(A∪B)∩y∈(A∩C)
(x,y)∈(A∪B)∩(A∩C)
(x,y)∈(A∪B)×(A∩C)
Does it enough? 
⟹
(x,y)∈(A∪B)×(A∪C)
x∈(A∪B)∩y∈(A∪C)
[(x∈A)∪(x∈B)]∩[(y∈A)∪(y∈C)]
How do I continue?
```

Comment: Have you tried some small examples?

Comment: What have you tried so far? One general tip for showing set equalities is to show that the left side is a subset of the right side and vice versa. That is to say, you pick an arbitrary element of the left set and show that this element lies in the right set by applying the definitions successively. Then, do the same in the other direction.

Comment: @EuklidAlexandria.  Wrong approach.

Comment: @WilliamElliot Why is it wrong? I only say how to show a set equality in general. If the OP’s sets are actually equal is a different story.

Comment: Another general tip for spotting some obviously false statements... if you were to look at the sizes of the relative sets, if the sizes are obviously not equal, then the proposed identity is also false.  In this case, letting $a,b,c$ be the sizes of $A,B,C$ respectively and the sets are disjoint, the cardinality of the left would be $a^2+bc$ compared to the right which is $(a+b)\cdot (a+c) = a^2+ab+ac+bc$.  Obviously $a^2+bc\neq a^2+ab+ac+bc$, so the proposed identity is false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To prove/disprove that: $$(A \times A) \cup(B \times C)=(A \cup B) \times(A \cup C)$$
So to prove it true, we need to show: $$
(A \cup B) \times(A \cup C) \subset(A \times A) \cup(B \times C)
$$
and $$
(A \times A) \cup(B \times C) \subset(A \cup B) \times(A \cup C)
$$

To disprove, problve any one of two expressions wrong.

So let $(x, y) \in (A \times A) \cup(B \times C)$, where $x$ and $y$ are two elements.
$$ 
\Rightarrow (x, y) \in (A \times A) \cup(B \times C)
$$

$$
\Rightarrow (x, y) \in A \times A \text { or } (x, y) \in B \times C
$$
**Note**: Here I have used "or" in inclusive way.

---

If only $$
 (x, y) \in A \times A
$$
$$
\Rightarrow \quad x \in A \text { and } y \in A
$$
$$
\Rightarrow x \in A \cup B \text { and } y \in A \cup C
$$
$$
So \quad(x, y) \in(A \cup B) \times(A \cup C)
$$

---

If only
$$
(x, y) \in B \times C
$$

$$\Rightarrow \quad x \in B\text { and } y \in C$$

$$
\Rightarrow \quad x \in B\cup A \text { and } y \in C\cup A
$$

$$\Rightarrow \quad(x, y) \in(A \cup B) \times(A \cup C)$$

---

Clearly in both cases we get the same result. Hence the third case is just a tautology, so we don't need consider  that case of "If $ (x, y) \in A \times A \text { and } (x, y) \in B \times C
$". [If you dont understand what I mean by "third case" then I suggest you read [this](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-an-inclusive-or-and-an-exclusive-or) and [this](http://web.mnstate.edu/peil/MDEV102/U1/S3/Union3.htm) ].

From both cases we can say that: $$(A \times A) \cup(B \times C) \subset(A \cup B) \times(A \cup C)$$

̷I̷ ̷h̷a̷v̷e̷ ̷o̷n̷l̷y̷ ̷p̷r̷o̷v̷e̷ ̷t̷h̷e̷ ̷f̷i̷r̷s̷t̷ ̷p̷a̷r̷t̷.̷ ̷Y̷o̷u̷ ̷s̷h̷o̷u̷l̷d̷ ̷p̷r̷o̷v̷e̷ ̷t̷h̷e̷ ̷o̷t̷h̷e̷r̷ ̷p̷a̷r̷t̷ ̷y̷o̷u̷r̷s̷e̷l̷f̷.̷

So to prove(disprove) second case let's assume $(p,q)$ belongs to $(A \cup B) \times(A \cup C)$. [Please note that I am taking two new elements $p$ and $q$ instead of $x$ and $y$, you should also take new elements while proving the second part, for proof to be general.]
So we get: $$
(p, q) \in(A \cup B) \times(A \cup C)
$$

$$
\Rightarrow p \in A \cup B \text { and } q \in A \cup C
$$

$$
(p \in A \text { or } p \in B) \text { and }(q \in A \text { or } q \in C)
$$

Now we have 6 six cases, ie,
$$
\begin{array}{l}
\text { 1) If only } p \in A \text { and } q \in A \\
\Rightarrow(p, q) \in A \times A \\
\Rightarrow(p, q) \in(A \times A) \cup(B \times C)
\end{array}
$$
2) If only $p \in A$ and only $q \in C$ $$
\Rightarrow(p, q) \notin(A \times A),(B \times C)
$$ [Why? Think about it. Hint: only]

Now you can see that for  **not every** $$
(p, q) \in(A \cup B) \times(A \cup C)
$$ 
$$
(p, q) \notin(A \times A),(B \times C)
$$

So we don't need to consider other cases,[but i suggest you do it, for the sake of practice].

Hence $$
(A \cup B) \times(A \cup C) \subset(A \times A) \cup(B \times C)
$$ is a false statement.  $Q.E.D$

**Advice**: OP[ questioner] is using $\cup$ in the sense of 'or'. Please don't. $\cup$ is an operation between two sets, it is not short way of writing 'or'. The short of writing 'or' is the symbol of 'reversed caret' $\lor$.

And please note that people who are on this site, are real human they, are not computers. Typing answer takes effort. So please show some effort in asking questions. You can do this by showing your own answers, even if that's wrong. 
For more information go to this [link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: Useless as empty B is a counter example.

Comment: @WilliamElliot what?

Comment: I suspect that @WilliamElliot is referring to how an empty $B$ counts as a counterexample to what you have written... but what you have written has an obvious typo in it.  It should have been $(A\color{red}{\cup} B)\times (A\cup C)$ rather than $(A\times B)\times (A\cup C)$.  Having an empty $B$ does not work as a counterexample to the *true* statement $(A\times A)\cup (B\times C)\subseteq (A\cup B)\times (A\cup C)$, which should have been clear from context was what was intended to have been written.

Comment: @JMoravitz thanks for correcting the typo. 

Comment: How do I continue?
 (A∪B)×(A∪C)=(A×A)∪(B×C)
⟸
(x,y)∈(A×A)∪(B×C)
(x,y)∈(A×A)∪(x,y)∈(B×C)
(x∈A∩y∈A)∪(x∈B∩y∈C)
(x∈A∪x∈B)∩(y∈A∪y∈C)
x∈(A∪B)∩y∈(A∩C)
(x,y)∈(A∪B)∩(A∩C)
(x,y)∈(A∪B)×(A∩C)
I didn't understood why you splited the 'IF's. Does right (the way I wrote it)?
⟹
(x,y)∈(A∪B)×(A∪C)
x∈(A∪B)∩y∈(A∪C)
[(x∈A)∪(x∈B)]∩[(y∈A)∪(y∈C)]
How do I continue?

Comment: @masha i have completed the answer. Check it Now!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

What if $A=\{a\}, B=\{b\}$ and $C=\{c\}$

> $(b,a)$ is an element of the RHS.  Is it an element of the LHS?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: You need to think about the meaning of cartesian product and union. And then describe both sides in those terms.

$A \times B $ is the set of all ordered pairs say $(x,y)$ such that $x \in A$ and $y \in B$

$A \cup B $ is the set of all elements,say $x$, such that $x \in A$ or $x \in B$